# fields in an Arraylist of objects gets overriden in loop

Tags: java, arraylist

here's my code snippet ->

```
private List<SDR> addDetails(List<SDR> list) {
        for(SDR item: list) {
                xyz = calculateValue(item);  // this method returns different values for every item
                item.setDetail1(xyz);
                System.out.println("getDetail1 before -> ", item.getDetail1());
        }
        System.our.println();
        for(SDR item: list) {
            System.out.println("getDetail1 after -> ", item.getDetail1());
        }
}
```

The output of this snippet comes out to be :

```
getDetail1 before -> 12
getDetail1 before -> 13
getDetail1 before -> 14

getDetail1 after -> 14
getDetail1 after -> 14
getDetail1 after -> 14
```

i dont understand what i am doing wrong here. why are the values getting overriden here, even though i am looping on SDR class and updating the particular `'item'`

EDIT:

the SDR class :

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SDR {
    private String id;
    private String detail1;
}
```

the `calculateValue` takes in the item, searches in the database the entry with `item.id == _id` and returns the detail1 string.

Any help would be highly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: what is inside of the `calculateValue `', `setDetail1` and `getDetail1` methods?

Comment: To help you debug we need code which we could run and reproduce described problem. So to get proper answers quicker consider creating [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (a.k.a. [MCVE])

Comment: @JeffScottBrown updated the description

Comment: Where is the list coming from? It seems the source itself contains reference to the same item thrice

Comment: "item.id == _id" - Is `id` a primary key in the database?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown item is not stored anywhere in the database. the configs corresponding to item.id are stored in a collection which has the primary key(_id) equals to item.id. So a document of the collection looks like this -- {_id: "abc", detail1: "12"}

Comment: " item is not stored anywhere in the database" - Gotcha.  I was confused by "searches in the database the entry with item.id == _id".

Comment: @ChetanAhirrao i debugged the list and this is what the list looks like. `[SDR(id=APP12, channel=DIGITAL, detail1=null …), `
 `SDR(id=APP13, channel=DIGITAL, detail1=null …),`
 `SDR(id=APP14, channel=DIGITAL, detail1=null …)]`